# How to send fields and files in the same form submit in NodeJS/Multer?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

My problem is that I can't get the req.body and req.file object when I post to /new, but everything is fine and the file is being uploaded in my folder. I just can't get access to the req.body and req.file objects. It returns [object Object] when I log req.body in the console and for req.file it logs undefined.

I've done some research and I found that you can't encode multipart/form-data with body-parser, but I need to have it because I can't send files without it.

```
var router = require('express').Router(),
    multer = require('multer'),
    path = require('path'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    middleware = require('../middleware'),
    User = require('../models/User'),
    Ad = require('../models/Ad');

// Storage setup
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: './public/uploads/',
  filename: function(req, file, done) {
    done(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

// Upload setup
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 3000000
  }
}).single('banner');

// Check file type
function checkFileType(file, callback) {
  // Allowed extensions
  var fileTypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
  // Check extention
  var extname = fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  // Check mime type
  var mimeType = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (mimeType && extname) {
    return callback(null, true);
  }
  callback(null, false);
}

router.get('/new', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  res.render('new');
});

router.post('/new', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  var adObj = {
    owner: req.user,
    url: req.user.url,
    paymentType: req.body.paymentType,
    transactionId: '',
    banner: ''
  };

  if (adObj.paymentType === 'paid') {
    adObj.transactionId = req.body.transactionId;
  }

  upload(req, res, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash('error', err.message);
      return res.redirect('/new');
    }
    adObj.banner = '/uploads/' + req.file.filename;
  });

  var ad = new Ad(adObj);
  ad.save();

  req.flash('success', 'Successfully added new ad.');
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

```html
<form class="main-form" action="/new" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="url" name="url" placeholder="Website URL" required>
      <select class="select-ad-type" name="paymentType">
        <option value="free" selected>Free Ad</option>
        <option value="paid">Sponsored Ad - $10</option>
      </select>
      <div class="transaction-section">
        <p>Send $10 to example@gmail.com and type your transaction id below. Your ad will be displayed in the "SPONSORED ADS" section in less than 24 hours.</p>
        <input type="text" name="transactionId" placeholder="Transaction Id">
      </div>
      <input type="file" name="banner" required>
      <button><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting the errors because you are trying to access the values before actual parsing by `multer` happens. You have rightly pointed out that `body-parser` doesn't work for `multipart-data`, but in `multipart-data` form-type,  `multer` can parse both `file` and other fields in the `form`, that's why we can access both `req.file` and `req.body`.

Make sure you access it in `upload(req, res, function(err) { // req.body and req.file })`

Also, there is an issue related to asynchronous code.

**Solution:**

```
router.post('/new', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
       if (err) {
          req.flash('error', err.message);
          return res.redirect('/new');
       }

       var adObj = {
          owner: req.user,
          url: req.user.url,
          paymentType: req.body.paymentType,
          transactionId: '',
          banner: ''
       };

       if (adObj.paymentType === 'paid') {
         adObj.transactionId = req.body.transactionId;
       }

       adObj.banner = '/uploads/' + req.file.filename;

       var ad = new Ad(adObj);
       ad.save();

       req.flash('success', 'Successfully added new ad.');
       return res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spent hours on it , need to make sure you access the req.body. under upload(req,res,err {